# cannot update angular in bower

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm trying to update my angular to 1.3.17 to 1.3.19 but I'm running into issues. The command I'm running is

> bower install angular#1.3.19

```
bower install angular#1.3.19
bower angular#1.3.19        not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.19
bower angular#1.3.19           resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.19
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.19       not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.19          resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.3.19
bower angular#1.3.17                not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.17
bower angular#1.3.17                   resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.17
bower angular-sanitize#~1.3.19      not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-sanitize#~1.3.19         resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-resource#~1.3.19      not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-resource#~1.3.19         resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.3.19
bower angular#~1.3.19               not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.19
bower angular#~1.3.19                  resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.19
bower angular#~1.3.14               not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.14
bower angular#~1.3.14                  resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.14
bower angular-messages#~1.3.19      not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-messages#~1.3.19         resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.19         not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.3.19
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.19            resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.3.19
bower angular#>=1.3.0                   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#>=1.3.0                 validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.0
bower angular#>=1.2                     cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#>=1.2                   validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                  cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5          validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2.26 <=1.5
bower angular-filter#0.5.5              cached git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git#0.5.5
bower angular-filter#0.5.5            validate 0.5.5 against git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git#0.5.5
bower angular#*                         cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#*                       validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower angular-messages#~1.3.19        download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular#1.3.17                  download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.17.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.19                 download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.14                 download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular#1.3.19                  download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.19.tar.gz
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.19         download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular-sanitize#~1.3.19        download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.19           download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular-resource#~1.3.19        download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource/archive/v1.3.20.tar.gz
bower angular-messages#~1.3.19         extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-sanitize#~1.3.19         extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.19                  extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#1.3.17                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.14                  extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-resource#~1.3.19         extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.19            extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#1.3.19                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.19          extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-messages#~1.3.19          EACCES EACCES, rename '/var/folders/48/hnxrs7kn41g8ldgsvvc85xy00000gp/T/username/bower/angular-messages-2047-hHk4Xg'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, rename '/var/folders/48/hnxrs7kn41g8ldgsvvc85xy00000gp/T/username/bower/angular-messages-2047-hHk4Xg'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:45:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
System info:
Bower version: 1.5.2
Node version: 0.12.7
OS: Darwin 14.5.0 x64
```

Comment: The current user does not have write permissions for that path.

Comment: Try `bower cache clean` then `bower install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually deleting whatever is in the /Users/username/.cache folder and running bower cache clean . Then running bower install again.